# 401 Permission Error with Balanced Payments

Tags: ios, objective-c, http, parse-platform, balanced-payments

I'm using Parse.Cloud.httpRequest and I need to send basic authentication with only a username to balanced payments. Where does this go and what would that look like? I tried setting it in the Headers but that's not working.

```
 Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
          method:'POST',
          url: customerUrl,
          headers:{
            "Content-Type"      : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
               "Accept"         : "application/vnd.api+json;revision=1.1",
               "Authorization"  : balancedSecret
          },
          body:bodyJsonString,
          success: function(httpResponse) {
            console.log(httpResponse.text);
            response.success(httpResponse.text);
          },
          error: function(httpResponse) {
            console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
            response.error(httpResponse.text);

          }
    });
```

When I call the function I get:

```
"errors": [
    {
      "status": "Unauthorized",
      "category_code": "authentication-required",
      "description": "Not permitted to perform create on customers. Your request id is OHMca9c440a0a7811e4ba9202a1fe52a36c.",
      "status_code": 401,
      "category_type": "permission",
      "request_id": "OHMca9c440a0a7811e4ba9202a1fe52a36c"
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"Authorization"  : balancedSecret
```

This is going to be wrong. You use the secret as the username, and nothing as the password. You then concatenate them together, base64 encode them, and pass *that* as the value of the auth header.

I don't have the setup to double check this, but this should work as the value:

```
"Basic " + encodeBase64(balancedSecret + ":")
```

Giving this code:

```
authHeader = "Basic " + btoa(balancedSecret + ":")
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
      method:'POST',
      url: customerUrl,
      headers:{
        "Content-Type"      : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
           "Accept"         : "application/vnd.api+json;revision=1.1",
           "Authorization"  : authHeader
      },
      body:bodyJsonString,
      success: function(httpResponse) {
        console.log(httpResponse.text);
        response.success(httpResponse.text);
      },
      error: function(httpResponse) {
        console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
        response.error(httpResponse.text);

      }
});
```